# Do sorted and distinct immediately process the stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine I have something that looks like this:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(2,1,3,5,6,7,9,11,10)
            .distinct()
            .sorted();
```

The javadocs for both `distinct()` and `sorted()` say that they are "stateful intermediate operation". Does that mean that internally the stream will do something like create a hash set, add all the stream values, then seeing `sorted()` will throw those values into a sorted list or sorted set?  Or is it smarter than that?

In other words, does `.distinct().sorted()` cause java to traverse the stream twice or does java delay that until a terminal operation is performed (such as `.collect`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have asked a loaded question, implying that there had to be a choice between two alternatives.

The stateful intermediate operations have to store data, in some cases up to the point of storing all elements before being able to pass an element downstream, but that doesn’t change the fact that this work is deferred until a terminal operation has been commenced.

It’s also not correct to say that it has to “traverse the stream twice”. There are entirely different traversals going on, e.g. in the case of `sorted()`, first, the traversal of the source filling on internal buffer that will be sorted, second, the traversal of the buffer. In case of `distinct()`, no second traversal happens in the sequential processing, the internal `HashSet` is just used to determine whether to pass an element downstream.

So when you run

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(2,1,3,5,3)
    .peek(i -> System.out.println("source: "+i))
    .distinct()
    .peek(i -> System.out.println("distinct: "+i))
    .sorted()
    .peek(i -> System.out.println("sorted: "+i));
System.out.println("commencing terminal operation");
stream.forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.println("terminal: "+i));
```

it prints

```
commencing terminal operation
source: 2
distinct: 2
source: 1
distinct: 1
source: 3
distinct: 3
source: 5
distinct: 5
source: 3
sorted: 1
terminal: 1
sorted: 2
terminal: 2
sorted: 3
terminal: 3
sorted: 5
terminal: 5
```

showing that nothing happens before the terminal operation has been commenced and that elements from the source immediately pass the `distinct()` operation (unless being duplicates), whereas all elements are buffered in the `sorted()` operation before being passed downstream.

It can further be shown that `distinct()` does not need to traverse the entire stream:

```
Stream.of(2,1,1,3,5,6,7,9,2,1,3,5,11,10)
    .peek(i -> System.out.println("source: "+i))
    .distinct()
    .peek(i -> System.out.println("distinct: "+i))
    .filter(i -> i>2)
    .findFirst().ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("found: "+i));
```

prints

```
source: 2
distinct: 2
source: 1
distinct: 1
source: 1
source: 3
distinct: 3
found: 3
```

As explained and demonstrated by [Jose Da Silva’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291012/2711488), the amount of buffering may change with ordered parallel streams, as partial results must be adjusted before they can get passed to downstream operations.

Since these operations do not happen before the actual terminal operation is known, there are more optimizations possible than currently happen in OpenJDK (but may happen in different implementations or future versions). E.g. `sorted().toArray()` may use and return the same array or `sorted().findFirst()` may turn into a `min()`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Acording to the javadoc both [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) and [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) methods are stateful intermediate operations.

The [StreamOps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) says the following about this operations:

> Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. As a result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may need to buffer significant data.

But the collect of the stream, happens only in the terminal operation (e.g. `toArray`, `collect` or `forEach`), both operations are processed in the pipeline and the data flows through it. Still, one important thing to note is the order in which this operations are executed, the javadoc of the `distinct()` method says:

> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter order is preserved.) For unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made.

---

For sequential streams, when this stream is sorted, the only element checked is the previous, when is not sorted a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is used internally instead, for this reason executing `distinct` after `sort` results in a better performance.

(note: as commented by Eugene the performance gain may be tiny in this secuential streams, specially when the code is hot, but still avoids the creation of that extra temporal `HashSet`)

Here you can see more about the order of `distinct` and `sort`:

[Java Streams: How to do an efficient "distinct and sort"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806467/java-streams-how-to-do-an-efficient-distinct-and-sort)

---

By the other hand, for parallel streams the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) says:

> Preserving stability for distinct() in parallel pipelines is relatively expensive (requires that the operation act as a full barrier, with substantial buffering overhead), and stability is often not needed. Using an unordered stream source (such as generate(Supplier)) or removing the ordering constraint with BaseStream.unordered() may result in significantly more efficient execution for distinct() in parallel pipelines, if the semantics of your situation permit.

A [full barrier operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189387/parallel-processing-with-infinite-stream-in-java) means that:

> All the upstream operations must be performed before the downstream can start. There are only two full barrier operations in Stream API: .sorted() (every time) and .distinct() (in ordered parallel case).

For this reason, when using parallel streams the opposite order is normally better (as long as the current stream is unordered), that is the use of `distinct` before `sorted`, because sorted can start to receive elements while distinct is being processed.

Using the opposite order, first sorting (an unordered parallel stream) and then using distinct, puts a barrier in both, first all elements have to be processed (flow) for `sort`, then all for `distinct`.

Here is an example:

```java
Function<String, IntConsumer> process = name ->
        idx -> {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom
                    .current().nextInt(3)); // handle exception or use 
                                            // LockSupport.parkNanos(..) sugested by Holger
            System.out.println(name + idx);
        };
```

The below function receives a name, and retuns a int consumer that sleeps from 0-2 seconds and then prints.

```java
IntStream.range(0, 8).parallel() // n > number of cores
        .unordered() // range generates ordered stream (not sorted)
        .peek(process.apply("B"))
        .distinct().peek(process.apply("D"))
        .sorted().peek(process.apply("S"))
        .toArray(); // terminal operation
```

This will print, Mix of B's and D's and then all S's (no barrier in `distinct`).

If you change the order of `sorted` and `distinct`:

```
        // ... rest
        .sorted().peek(process.apply("S"))
        .distinct().peek(process.apply("D"))
        // ... rest
```

This will print, all B's then all S's and then all D's (barrier in `distinct`).

If you want to try even more add an `unordered` after `sorted` again:

```java
        // ... rest
        .sorted().unordered().peek(process.apply("S"))
        .distinct().peek(process.apply("D"))
        // ... rest
```

This will print, All B's and then a mix of S's and D's (no barrier in `distinct` again).

---

Edit:

Changed a little the code to a better explanation and use of `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3)` as sugested.

Comment: `distinct()` does *not* need to collect the entire stream. Further, you should not use `new Random().nextInt() % 3`, as the result can become negative. There is a simple dedicated method to get a bounded int: `new Random().nextInt(3)`. But the better alternative is `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3)`. By the way, Java even has a not-so-well-known method that allows sleeping without the need for exception handling: `LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3)));`

Comment: @JoseDaSilva the performance diff is *really* tiny when the code is hot... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624167/1059372

Comment: @Holger about the ramdom you're correct and i changed by `ThreadLocalRandom`, still that part of the code is not the most important. Didn't know about `LockSupport.parkNanos()` good tip. And finally `distinct` does in fact need to collect the entire stream (is a barrier operation) on ordered parallel streams, like says in the javadoc and the code shows.

Comment: @Eugene yes I added a note in sequaltial stream's part, but even throgh the performance gain is insignificant, exists. Thanks by the comment.

Comment: @Holger * collect is not the appropriate word, needs to wait the operation ends.

Comment: The word “collect” wasn’t problematic, the meaning was understood. The point is, only in the specific case of parallel ordered processing, `distinct` needs the barrier. In case of sequential or unordered processing, it does not need it. And even in the case of a parallel ordered stream, the worker processing the leftmost chunk doesn’t actually need to wait for the completion of the others. It’s just an implementation specific limitation that all workers wait.

Comment: In the comment collect wasn't the appropriate word, in the answer, the explanation wans't clear, i mean that both operations were collected, but didn't specify that this happen in the end of the pipeline (and only once with the terminal operation). That's why i edited. And about the last, i know is not a need, but how you said that is how it's implemented.